# Can't save images on internal memory android lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm having problem saving jpg and png images on internal memory on Android Lollipop. I'm using a simple application that download (directly or asynchronously) an image from URL an show it on imageview and than it's possible to save it in the internal memory previous create an album on image gallery. The problem is that download the image, after it show it inside imageview but it does not save in the internal memory. It show that it save a file with the right name inside the new album but the file has 0.00 bytes. The app work fine in kit kat. I'm trying with this sample because I'm running the same problem in another app that, as the sample do, works fine in kit kat and does not in lollipop.